# how to choose a property of an object inside an array inside model?

Tags: javascript

My model is:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");



var invoice = new mongoose.Schema({
    invoiceDate: String,
    invoiceNumber: String,
    orderInfo: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "order"
        }
    ],
    customerInfo: [{
       id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "customer"
        },
    customerName: String,
    }]
});

//EXPORT
module.exports = mongoose.model("invoice", invoice);
```

and I want to show the data in this way:

```
<tbody>
    <%data.forEach(function(data){%>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/showInvoice/<%=data._id%></td>
            <td>
                <%=data._id%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=data.invoiceDate%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=data.invoiceNumber%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=data.customerInfo.customerName%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%});%>
</tbody>
```

But I got an error which says:

> can not use property customerName of undefined

that's strange because `<%=data.customerInfo%>` works and shows me an object, but I just need only the `customerName` property.